# Rails: Can you create a new database relation using filter parameters from another (associated) database with the .where() method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In my case I have two models, **Tournament** and **Result**. I want to generate a table for career tournament results, with each row being the yearly results.

I have a column called **"season_year"** in the **Tournament** model.

I want to be able to display all Results where the associated tournament has a **season_year** value of x ("2022" in the example below, to keep it simple).

Here is the model associations:

```
class Tournament < ApplicationRecord
has_many :results
end

class Result < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :tournament
end
```

But when I try anything ***like*** the following, it does not work:

```
<% Result.where(member_id: @member.id, tournament.season_year: "2022").each do |result| %>
    <tr>
       <td><%= result.place %></td>
       ...
    </tr>
 <% end %>
```

It doesn't like tournament.season_year since that is not a column in the Result model. Is there an easy way to do this or another method I should be using? Why can't I use its association with the Tournament model to filter out the Result entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Result.where(member_id: @member.id, tournament.season_year: "2022")
```

to

```
Result.joins(: tournament)
      .where(member_id: @member.id, tournaments: { season_year: "2022" })
```

Note the singular `tournament` in the `joins` because that is the name of the association (`belongs_to :tournament` in this case). But the plural `tournaments` in the `where` because that is the actual table name.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I could not find this answer through hours of searching. I am now replacing my nested do loops with this line :D I got it working...but I was using .pluck to get the season year from all the Tournament entries, looping through each year, then looping through each result and comparing if the Result and Tournament ID matched.

Comment: @railsnoob You are welcome. Please consider upvoting an answer when it was helpful and accepting when it solved your problem. That is a way to say "thank you" and to indicate to others that your issue is fixed.

Comment: I will once i have enough reputation lol